# What's the point of OpenZeppelin Counters library

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I've been studying ERC721 token smart contracts and saw Counters library.
I can see it being used when token is being minted with `.increment()` and then you can check total supply with `.current()`. But what's the point of it? It just adds some basic stuff and makes contract bigger, it's easier to make an uint variable and increment it with `+= 1` on mint and return it on `totalSupply` function.

Comment: It's just generally a good practice. Yes, `counter++` can do the same job with `counter.increment()`, however, it adds readability to solidity especially when Solidity code is part of the marketing material for transparency. Not only professional coders can read it, but also rookies, outsiders, or investors. Readability matters.

Comment: imo it obfuscates code. I am not a fan of it.

Comment: I also find it less readable than just doing it manually and am not a fan. It feels bizarrely industrial for such a basic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/utils#Counters

Seems that one of the key feature is ensuring that its only ever incremented and decremented by 1. The readability is a plus as well.